# "The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:" what to do?

Tags: apt

After trying to open and install google earth through the terminal it keeps bringing up this message.

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 language-pack-kde-en kde-l10n-engb
  libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 thunderbird-globalmenu language-pack-kde-en-base
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
```

I am wondering what I can do next?

Comment: I would run `apt-get autoremove && apt-get dist-upgrade` if I were you.

Comment: @DavidFoerster - The questions are essentially the same. I consider that the one posted first is to be considered the "original", and the others "duplicates", regardless of *most (just leaving the door open for possible exceptions)* other factors. Quantity and quality of answers is not such an exception. Readers would still be able to see both threads, so readership would not be impaired. Flagging would lead future posters of answers to posting at the original OP, as I guess it is mostly appropriate.

Comment: @sancho.s: What are you trying to accomplish when you want to redirect readers to a resource of inferior quality compared to this one? There has never been a rule that the linked question must be older than the source – otherwise it would be very simple to enforce it during the flagging process.

Comment: The info with `automatically installed and no longer required` is misleading: the message appears before I uninstalled the package. I did `apt uninstall pkg` and the output is `..Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:..`. Correct should be `use apt autoremove to remove them AFTER you installed your pkg.`.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/202637/67045 - sometimes the system thinks they are not required as you didn't explicitly install them via `apt`, however, you may be using them as they were installed via a different method. Use caution.

Answer (score 29):

Is telling you that those packages that were automatically installed due dependency resolution, are no longer required, as the packages that depend on them has been removed or have other dependencies. You can remove them with a simple:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

But you might want to upgrade your other packages too:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 13):

Those packages were installed as requirements to other packages, which you've now removed. The system now thinks they can safely be removed.

You could remove them with:

```
apt-get autoremove
```

Or when you uninstall packages, use

```
apt-get remove --auto-remove <package-name>
```

If you want to suppress the message and keep those packages installed (perhaps you're now using them), use:

```
apt-get install <package-name>
```

or:

```
apt-mark showauto | xargs apt-get install
```

Comment: `apt-mark showauto | xargs apt-get install` did it for me when nothing else would work... Thanks!